# Spark Streaming vs Structured Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

The last months I've been using quite a lot Structured Streaming for implementing Stream Jobs (after using Kafka a lot). After reading the book Stream Processing with Apache Spark i was having this question: Is there any point or use cases where i would use Spark Streaming instead of Structured Streaming? Should i invest some time getting into it or since im already using Spark Structured Streaming i should stick with it and there is no benefit on the previous API.
Would appreciate any opinion/insight

Answer (score 2):

Hi Sharing my personal experience.

Structured streaming is the future for spark based streaming implementation. It provides higher level of abstraction and other great features. However there are few restrictions.

i have had to switch to spark streaming on few occasions due to the flexibility offered by it. One recent example is, we had to perform Joins with static reference data, however Outer joins are not supported in Structured streaming. This can be accomplished with Spark streaming.

With the newer spark version 2.4, Structured streaming is much improved with support for foreachBatch sink which gives similar flexibility offered by spark streaming.

My personal thought is having the knowledge of spark streaming is helpful and you might have to use it depending on your use case.